# I have to ping in command prompt and save output to excel workbook

Tags: vbscript

I have to ping in command prompt and save output to excel workbook. How to save command prompt data into excel workbook by *vbscript*? I have code for text file:

```
 Dim oShell,fs
 Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
 oShell.run "cmd.exe /C ping 192.168.1.2"& str & " > log.txt"

set objLog = fs.OpenTextFile("myLogFile.txt", 8, true, 0)
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Comment: The `ping` output seems to be pretty unstructured while a `csv` (or `xls`)  is presumed to be structured in columns (am I right?) Read and parse the `log.txt` line by line…

Comment: yes it is unstructured.how to read it line by line.please help me

Comment: Get an inspiration in [How Can I Convert a Comma-Separated Values File to a Tab-Separated Values File](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/04/06/how-can-i-convert-a-comma-separated-values-file-to-a-tab-separated-values-file/) article.

Comment: i don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a temp log file which stored Ping's result. You can easily use .Exec method to read from console. Sample code below.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExec = objShell.Exec("cmd.exe /c ping 192.168.1.2")
strOut = objExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
Set objExec = Nothing : Set objShell = Nothing

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
objExcel.Visible = False
Set Sheet1 = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
arr = Split(strOut, vbNewLine)
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    Sheet1.Range("A" & i+1).Value = arr(i)
Next
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\PingResult.xlsx"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Set Sheet1 = Nothing : Set objExcel = Nothing

msgbox "done"
wscript.quit
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off

SET mm=%date:~4,2%

SET dd=%date:~7,2%

SET yy=%date:~12,2%

SET hh=%time:~0,2%

SET min=%time:~3,2%

SET ss=%time:~6,2%

ping -n 4 **IP ADDRESS HERE** | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"

if %errorlevel% == 0 (

  echo **DEVICE NAME HERE**,**IP ADDRESS HERE**,%date%,%hh%_%min%_%ss%,SUCCESS > .\output.csv

) else (

  echo **DEVICE NAME HERE**,**IP ADDRESS HERE**,%date%,%hh%_%min%_%ss%,FAILURE > .\output.csv

)
```

Echo.

You can use this code to ping several IPS at a time and save the output as: "output.csv" with pinged time and date